How do I get the user email login with apple on firebase?
I want to implement login with Apple on my Flutter app. I'm using Firebase for this.
Now, the problem is that I can't get the user's email when signing in with an Apple ID, even though they are a new user.
This is all that I'm getting:
UserCredential("additionalUserInfo":"AdditionalUserInfo(isNewUser":true,
"profile":{
   "iat":1714135713,
   "c_hash":83URF98pSgLZ2ZsV7YW19g,
   "nonce":699e1e15c41c10679a119a2325a60a56bb2da5afcd423c42b9fd6e2871e51d6f,
   "sub":000565.c2f0908bed494d478df2889f96f21504.1752,
   "aud":"com.company.app",
   "auth_time":1714135713,
   "exp":1714222113,
   "nonce_supported":true,
   "iss":"https":
},
"providerId":"apple.com",
"username":null,
"authorizationCode":c5b85875dce1848f393dd2face77d7ef2.0.rvwv.YsJ3snH1OA2),
"credential":"AuthCredential(providerId":"apple.com",
"signInMethod":"apple.com",
"token":12913507168,
"accessToken":heres a accesstoken (doesn't contain the email)),
"user":"User(displayName":null,
"email":null,
"isEmailVerified":false,
"isAnonymous":false,
"metadata":"UserMetadata(creationTime":"2024-04-26 12":"48":35.707Z,
"lastSignInTime":"2024-04-26 12":"48":35.708Z),
"phoneNumber":null,
"photoURL":null,
"providerData",
[
   "UserInfo(displayName":null,
   "email":null,
   "phoneNumber":null,
   "photoURL":null,
   "providerId":"apple.com",
   "uid":000565.c2f0908bed494d478df2889f96f21504.1752)
],
"refreshToken":AMf-vByhoKeagZn3qHAp6AyAHIH0tfKT63vKSGHkgKOqGwGbCT9uewt8d89JWAbsIRy0IIexRCHzpnz5BEnDjnZwZQal2BThn4eO7m9rIvbfi1yg2ePEkXU5AM97bPDd50kU00_L7tXCXKrpXQ52-iPVay_LEoF0yxBlZRuWnSj__RHbAeeUiY8aEcE_IgLuvzeuHjns_sNao-IB0BUX9NZ7pNI4R6R6WQgVeK5XD5PArv7RPN5pGqOi6BxaR2nCIiuJ-5wqbERt,
"tenantId":null,
"uid":wfNTW2vFLXg0DXpm8Dow65G8Fu92)
)

How can I get the email? I need it from my backend.
